# Convert a CFNumberRef to NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, nsinteger, cfnumberref

```
#import "someClass.h"

@implementation someClass

- (NSInteger *)checkWakeOnLan {
    SCDynamicStoreRef ds = SCDynamicStoreCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("myapp"), NULL, NULL);
    CFDictionaryRef dr = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(ds, CFSTR("State:/IOKit/PowerManagement/CurrentSettings"));
    CFNumberRef wol=CFDictionaryGetValue(dr, CFSTR("Wake On LAN"));
    CFRelease(dr);
    CFRelease(ds);
```

here my problem, how to convert CFNumberRef to NSInteger,
i tryed again and again, but got anytime
"makes integer from pointer without cast"

```
    NSInteger *value = [... ?];
    return value;
}

- (IBAction)doStuff:(NSButton *)sender {
    [myBevelButton setState:[self checkWakeOnLan]]; //setState takes NSInteger
    //myBevelButton defined elsewhere, shows different icons 
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

//assuming you want to convert wol to NSNumber and then to NSInteger

```
NSNumber *nsnumber = (NSNumber*)wol;
NSInteger value = [nsnumber integerValue];
```

**NOTE:* You rarely need an NSInteger pointer. In your case you can quite easily use NSInteger. Also you need to change the method as `- (NSInteger)checkWakeOnLan`